How deep does a sphere sit in a hole?
Let's say there is a sphere of radius $r$ and a circular hole of radius of $x$. If $x<r$, how deep does the sphere sit inside the hole? I haven't been able to figure this out,
The amount the sphere dips is $\alpha$

I have only been able to derive the formula
$$\frac{\alpha^2+x^2}{2\alpha} = r $$
Any ideas?

You're almost there. Just solve for $\alpha.$ The two $\alpha$ values add up to $2r,$ and the smaller is the right one.n

The equation you derived is equivalent to $\alpha^2-2\alpha r +x^2=0$ and is a quadratic equation in the unknown $\alpha$. This can be solved using the usual formula for roots of quadratic equations. Edit: You'll get two possible roots, you'll still have to pick the correct one, Thomas' comment solves that.

Or you can just solve for the length of $AE$ using the Pythagorean  Theorem, and then subtract it from from $r.$

An alternative solution is just to note that $AE$ is a cathetus of the right triangle $AB'E$, and by Pythagoras', $AE = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. Now simply note $CE = \alpha$ adds to $AE$ to make $AC = r$. Subtract.

$$\alpha = r-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
I found $\alpha$ via the quadratic formula, it should be minus not plus because $\alpha$ cannot exceed r

Right, also, note that Thomas' second comment (or Deepak's) is way easier and avoids having to solve a quadratic equation. That's it, well done!
